# Error When Adding Near 1000 Comboboxes

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I work in the data acquisition field, and our customers needed a way to easily set several settings on up to 256 input channels. Each channel requires 4 combo boxes in order to represent all of the configurable options. [Here is a link to what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQxd6.jpg)

These combo boxes are created in a loop at run time using the following method:

```
Set obj = Worksheets("Synergy Setup").OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Link:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=ttl_width + cell_width, Top:=ttl_height, Width:=cell_width2, Height:=cell_height)
```

Everything works fine up to about ~243 channels (or close to 1000 combo boxes), and then I get the following error:

"Automation Error, Element Not Found, Error -2147319765"

Using MsgBoxes I have confirmed that it is indeed the aforementioned line of code that is causing this error, and it only occurs when I get close to 1000 combo boxes. <strike>Also, after this error has occured, everything in my excel file is broken, and I get the continually get the error "Object library invalid or contains references to object definitions that could not be found".</strike> (EDIT: not relevant)

To reiterate, this only happens with a large number of combo boxes. Any thoughts?

**EDIT: I wanted to follow up and say that the change to the in-cell combo boxes has not only fixed my issue, but sped up my design 10-fold, and to my surprise, greatly simplified the code as well!  Thanks!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can think about using *in cell drop-down lists* instead of the combo boxes.
[Like e.g. described here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-remove-a-drop-down-list-HP010342357.aspx). I think it will show better performance, too.

EDIT:
I captured a code with the macro recorder (I only eliminated the *select*):

```
With Range("B:B").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=values_colors"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

You can still capture the change of values, take a look at the `Worksheet_Change Event`.

Comment: I think perhaps you are right. Is it possible to programmatically create the in-cell drop-down lists and set the 'ListFillRange' and 'Name' of them at run time?


EDIT: I also need to be able to capture "on change" events so I can prevent the user from creating illegal combinations of settings on a given channel.

Comment: +1 Much better idea: to add the selection constraints, consider using `Dynamic Named Ranges` in combination with `Validation` - to start see Contextures.com [here](http://www.contextures.com/xldataval02.html) [and here](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal13.html)